# ¿Porque no funcionan las opciones al compilar y ejecutar en sublime text?

Tags: c++, sublimetext

Estoy intentando efectuar un archivo de configuración para Sublime Text, el problema es que quiero al presionar <kbd>F8</kbd> compilar y al presionar <kbd>F5</kbd> ejecutar el programa.

Estos son mis archivos de configuración, cuando intento compilar no funciona, me dice `no build system with variant compile`, pero cuando presiono <kbd>F5</kbd> compila y ejecuta.

###### **build.sublime-build**

```
{
    "cmd": ["g++", "-std=c++17", "-Wshadow", "-Wall", "-o", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}.exe", "$file", "-O2", "-Wno-unused-result"],
    "working_dir": "${file_path}",
    "selector": "source.cpp",
    "variants":
    [
        {
            "name": "Compile",
            "cmd": ["g++", "-std=c++17", "-Wshadow", "-Wall", "-o", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}.exe", "$file", "-O2", "-Wno-unused-result"]
        },
        {
            "name": "Run",
            "cmd": ["start", "cmd", "/k", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}.exe"],
            "shell": true
        }
    ]
}
```

###### **default.sublime-keymap**

```
[
    {
        "keys": ["f8"],
        "command": "build",
        "args": {
            "variant": "Compile"
        }
    },
    {
        "keys": ["f5"],
        "command": "build",
        "args": {
            "variant": "Run"
        }
    }
]
```